# Can't hide element on click for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element on my website, it looks like so:

```
<div class="nw_help"><div class="nw_help_content">...</div></div>
```

Easy stuff. Using CSS on nw_help:hover, nw_help_content becomes visible. In order to support touchscreens too, I have written the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nw_help').click(function() {
        $(this).find(".nw_help_content").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nw_help_content').click(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

The first function works flawlessly, the second one doesn't wanna work at all. I've checked if $('.nw_help_content').css('visibility', 'hidden'); is working in browser's console and it is.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance for your answer.

Edit: Now it hit me: the first function is triggered on clicking nw_help_content as well and it "neutralizes" the second function. But how to prevent it?

Comment: are you using firefox? because there are some known issues with toggling the `visibility`. Try `opacity` instead, just for checking if this works.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you have the visibility hidden on page render, the element is never rendered. You'll need event delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nw_help').click(function() {
        $(this).find(".nw_help_content").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.nw_help_content', function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

Also, only one DOM ready statement is needed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7sM3L/4/

Comment: @WojciechMaj This isn't actually the reason why it doesn't work. The first sentence is flat out false.

Comment: Yeah this is wrong, been trying to find where I read that, I probably just imagined it. Deleting. @WojciechMaj -- Can you unaccept this so I can delete?

Comment: @tymeJV No worries, I'm guessing you were thinking of display:none, in which case it would be true

Answer (score 0):

I suggest staying away from direct CSS rule manipulation on this. Just using jQuery show and hide will provide a more solid/reliable result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nw_help').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.nw_help_content').show();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nw_help_content').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working/ Since the divs are nested you are both events fire and the div is hidden and shown on same click.
use `toggle` instead.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.nw_help').click(function() {
            $(this).find(".nw_help_content").toggle();
        });
    });
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLgup/)

Answer (score 0):

As Zenith says, this is due to event bubbling...  Another solution is to bind the event only to the outer container and simply check for the visibilty:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nw_help').click(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('.nw_help_content');
        if(content.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            content.css('visibility','visible');
        } else {
            content.css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    });
});
```